# Project and restrict in relational algebra

Tags: relational-database, relational-algebra

The definition of the SELECT and PROJECT operators used below may be found in Chapter 6 of "Relational Database Design and Implementation", 4th Edition, Harrington, Jan L.

The SQL equivalent of the PROJECT (resp. RESTRICT) is SELECT (resp. WHERE with a predicate to reduce the number of elements in a relation). In the notation you propose (thank you for doing that) let us use b_pred for the application of the predicate "pred" to a relation to reduce its elements. Then a(b_pred(relation))=b_pred(a(relation)) iff b_pred does not eliminate the column(s) supporting the predicate "pred". Furthermore if b_pred uses a column which is removed by a, the RHS expression is incorrect.

**Question**: is the result always correct when the RESTRICT operation is performed first? It would be great to have a formal proof of that statement.

**Follow-up**: why would we ever be interested at all in considering the opposite order of the operations? I would guess that performance is the only possible reason, but I am not sure.

Thanks for your responses!

Comment: What do you mean, "is the result always correct when the restrict operation is performed first"? The result of what? Do you mean, is the order immaterial if the column(s) in the restriction aren't projected away? Also, please give a reference the version of relational algebra ou mean, since there are ones with different kinds of relations & operators.

Comment: You don't actually mean "commutes". An operator is commutative when op(a,b)=op(b,a). You sort of mean (parallel to matrix multiplication) that composition of functions is commutative for a=PROJECT & b=RESTRICT; except that those are not binary operators, since they each take a relation argument and another argument, and those other arguments are of different types. (Not that you have made clear just what operators you mean.) You maybe mean that for all attribute sets *s* & subsets of it *c*, composition does not commute for (unary) function pairs PROJECT-*s* &  RESTRICT-c.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. This may help: the SQL equivalent of the PROJECT (resp. RESTRICT) is SELECT (resp. WHERE with a predicate to reduce the number of elements in a relation). In the notation you propose (thank you for doing that) let us use b_pred for the application of the predicate "pred" to a relation to reduce its elements. Then a(b_pred(relation))=b_pred(a(relation)) iff b_pred does not eliminate the column(s) supporting the predicate "pred". Furthermore if b_pred uses a column which is removed by a, the RHS expression is incorrect. I hope this makes a bit more sense. Thanks!

Comment: I know what you meant. My point was, when you write something that doesn't make sense because it's sloppy ("commute") then the reader must first use the actual meanings of the words you wrote to try to make sense, then when sense cannot be made they must try to reverse engineer what you might have meant and should have written. Please edit your question so it says what you meant, not nonsense using a fancy term because you thought of it. You don't need "commute"; I only used it to show its proper use; don't use it. PS Maximize standard notation, eg OP(x, r) or RA OP x r (more than above).

Comment: Question updated - thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: A proof requires definitions & theorems which justify a further chain of theorems. You must agree with the definitions & theorems to agree that someone is giving a proof. So you must give some definitions & theorems for relations and operators or a reference whose definitions and theorems we can use before we start guessing at proofs whose definitions and theorems you might accept. (If you start with operator definitions that you accept and replace the calls in the conjecture that you wish to prove with those definitions, it is likely that you will be able to prove such a simple theorem.)

Comment: What definitions? Oh you mean, you are use of the operator names refers to those of the same name defined in the given reference. Please clarify that, and type the defintions in.

Comment: Great suggestions! Thank you for reminding me. Added a reference, hoping this would clarify it. Please excuse my initial lack of rigor. I did not know how this forum works in this area. Now I know. Thanks again, @philipxy. Your  suggestions are improving my expression already. Sorry to have made you spend so much time helping me out.

Comment: I'm sorry. I fear I may violate the copyright in the book if I typed in the definitions. I hope the language reads better.

Comment: Would that the questions in this forum be as "rigorous" (I would say *clear*) as you are now! Notice that all I am doing is asking that your question make sense and actually ask for what you want, by addressing the meanings of the words you have chosen but used fuzzily. I hope you will clarify even further. (Especially given Renzo's answer's rephrasing.)

Comment: Copyright allows fair use, which is currently ridiculously lax for educational purposes, being *an entire chapter*. (But I'm not a lawyer.) But if you understand the definition then you know what the operators do so you should be able to tell us; if you can't express it in your own words, it can hardly be said that you understand what the operators do. Anyway, if you are asking for a proof that you can presumably understand, then by definition of "proof" there are *some* definitions & theorems that you would accept as given. PS I am glad I am helping, it is a fun challenge to improve at it.

Comment: PS My god that (3rd edition) is a poor quality book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two rules that can be applied to change the order of restrictions and projections maintaining the semantics of the expression are the following:

π<sub>*Y*</sub>(σ<sub>ΦX</sub>(E)) = σ<sub>Φ*X*</sub>(π<sub>*Y*</sub>(E)), if X ⊆ Y

otherwise, if the condition concerns attributes X ⊈ Y:

π<sub>*Y*</sub>(σ<sub>ΦX</sub>(E)) = π<sub>*Y*</sub>(σ<sub>Φ*X*</sub>(π<sub>*XY*</sub>(E)))

where E is any relational expression producing a relation with a set of attributes that includes *X* and *Y*, π<sub>*X*</sub>(E) is the projection of E over the set of attributes *X* and σ<sub>ΦX</sub>(E) is the restriction over E with a condition ΦX over the set of attributes X.

These two rules are equivalence rules, so they can be applied in both directions. In general the optimizer tries to apply the restrictions before any other operation, if possible, and than to apply the projections before the joins.

**Added**

The first rule says that if you have a relation with attributes Z = Y ∪ W,  performing a restriction over a subset of the attributes of Y, and then projecting the result on Y, is equivalent to perform first the projection, and then the restriction.

This equivalence can be proved in the following way.

Given E a relation with attributes Z = Y ∪ W, the definition of restriction is:

σ<sub>ΦX</sub>(E) = { t | t ∈ E ∧ X ⊆ Z ∧ ΦX(t) }

that is, the set of all the tuples of E such that ΦX(t) is true.

The definition of projection is:

π<sub>*Y*</sub>(E) = { t<sub>1</sub> |  t ∈ E ∧ Y ⊆ Z ∧ t<sub>1</sub> = t[Y] }

that is the set of tuples obtained by considering, for each tuple t of E, a (sub)tuple containing only the attributes Y of t.

So,

π<sub>*Y*</sub>(σ<sub>ΦX</sub>(E)) = π<sub>*Y*</sub>(E') = 
{ t<sub>1</sub> |  t ∈ E' ∧ Y ⊆ Z ∧ t<sub>1</sub> = t[Y] }

where E' = σ<sub>ΦX</sub>(E) = { t | t ∈ E ∧ X ⊆ Z ∧ ΦX(t) }

Combining these two formulas, we get:

π<sub>*Y*</sub>(σ<sub>ΦX</sub>(E)) = { t<sub>1</sub> |  t ∈ E ∧ X ⊆ Z ∧ ΦX(t) ∧ Y ⊆ Z ∧ t<sub>1</sub> = t[Y] }

But since we know that X ⊆ Y, we can rewrite the formula as:

π<sub>*Y*</sub>(σ<sub>ΦX</sub>(E)) = { t<sub>1</sub> |  t ∈ E ∧ X ⊆ Y ⊆ Z ∧ ΦX(t) ∧ t<sub>1</sub> = t[Y] }        [1]

Starting from the other term,

σ<sub>Φ*X*</sub>(π<sub>*Y*</sub>(E)) = σ<sub>Φ*X*</sub>(E'') = { t | t ∈ E'' ∧ X ⊆ Z ∧ ΦX(t) }

where E'' = π<sub>*Y*</sub>(E) = { t<sub>1</sub> |  t ∈ E ∧ Y ⊆ Z ∧ t<sub>1</sub> = t[Y] }

Again, combining these two formulas and noting that X ⊆ Y, we get:

σ<sub>Φ*X*</sub>(π<sub>*Y*</sub>(E)) = { t<sub>1</sub> | t ∈ E ∧ X ⊆ Y ⊆ Z ∧ ΦX(t<sub>1</sub>) ∧  t<sub>1</sub> = t[Y] }        [2]

[1] = [2] if we can show that ΦX(t) = ΦX(t[Y]), and this is true since both conditions are true or false at the same time, given that the condition is concerns only the attributes X, which are present both in t and in t[Y] (since X ⊆ Y).

The second rule says that, if you have a relation with attributes Z = X ∪ Y ∪ W, with X - Y ≠ ∅ performing a restriction over the attributes of X, and then projecting the result on Y, is equivalent to perform first a projection over the attributes X ∪ Y, then perform the restriction, and finally perform a new projection over the attributes X.

Also in this case a formal proof can be given, by reasoning in an analogous way to the above proof, but it is omitted here for brevity.